# Ubuntu 23.04 (and 22.04.3) stuck on purple loading screen using VirtualBox 7 on MacOS (Catalina)

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, mac, 23.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 64-bit through Vitrualbox on my MacBook Pro (16 inch, 2019 running MacOS 10.15.2 Catalina). I have downloaded Virtualbox and followed the online tutorials to install Ubuntu but can't get passed the purple loading screen.

Image for reference, though its from google and an older version it is the same screen i am getting for 23.04 and 22.04.03: (https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F1096428%2Fvirtualbox-stuck-on-purple-loading-screen&psig=AOvVaw2ipDOVEDjeffm5JA2S-QOE&ust=1696610857425000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCOiD2o2u34EDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE)

I followed the installation steps and know I did that right, but when I click on Ubuntu in the menu on the left in VB it takes me to the purple loading screen and never gets passed it. I have allocated 32GB of Virtual Storage, 8GB of RAM, 4 Processors, and bumped up the Video Memory under Display settings to the max it goes (I believe its 128 MB). I also tried the "nomodeset" in the terminal when it first opens but that does not help either.

[Here is a link to the ISO I downloaded and am trying to use.](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) I am using the Ubuntu 23.04. I also tried the Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS but had the same issue.

The installation tutorials I looked at as well are linked here:
[From VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#fig-create-vm-name)
[From Youtube](https://youtu.be/yL689oca4GA?si=YBSRFNgeOeQtY1Bu)

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Is the purple screen blank or there is some text on the middle? You could try re-installing the operating system. To do that, you need to reboot the system. If re-installing the system lands you on the same screen, then you might have a corrupted system.

Comment: Thank you for this information! The purple screen says "Ubuntu 23.04" and has loading dots underneath that keep indicating something is loading but it never makes it passed that screen. I have tried deleting the Ubuntu setup on VirtualBox and reinstalling it, but have gotten the same result multiple times. I have even tried the previous version of Ubuntu (I believe 22.04.03) and got the same result as well. I got the Ubuntu download straight from their website, so if it is corrupted how can I get a version/download that isn't? Thank you again!

Comment: @kmr5763 The download from the website is never corrupted, but when burning the ISO file in a CD/Floppy can result in some errors, like a file not getting burned in the CD.

Comment: @newstupiddude The OP is trying to install in VirtualBox. So they're not burning the ISO onto a CD. Furthermore, the "hardware" is virtualized, so it can't be a hardware issue with respect to the "machine" used for the attempted installation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the ISO you're using? Can you provide a link to the tutorial you're following? Please update original question with this info. Do not put in a comment. Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestions. I have put links to the ISO and tutorials I followed for installation in the original question! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried VirtualBox 7 when first released. I encountered many problems. So, I am currently using VirtualBox 6.1.44. I have installed the Extension Pack. My Mac is a 2013 iMac with 16 GB of memory. Since the only internal drive is a HDD, the Mac boots from a faster external Samsung T7 SSD. The version of macOS is Catalina 10.15.7. I was able to download the `ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso` file. I successfully installed a BIOS booting Ubuntu using the default settings, except for the following.

- The memory was set to 4096 MB.
- The number of processors was set to 2 CPUs.
- The drive was set to 100 GB.
- The video memory was set to 128 MB.
- The network was set to Bridged Adaptor.
- The USB Controller was set to USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller.

Before installing Guest Additions, I needed to [enter the following commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035030/this-system-is-currently-not-set-up-to-build-kernel-modules-when-trying-to-ins) in a Terminal application window on Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc make perl dkms
reboot
```

Afterwards, I did successfully install Guest Additions.

---

I also successfully tried a clean EFI booting install. Here I used the same procedure as above, except I added the following change to the settings.

- Enable EFI (special OSes only) was selected.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I was able to install VirtualBox 6.1.44 along with Ubuntu 23.04 and this worked! No more issues with the install and I now have it up and running. Thank you for your help!