# VirtualBox doesn't start any VMs on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, 22.04, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox form the official website but it fails to start any VMs
[image]

Trying to follow the instructions doesn't help.
[image]

I also followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035030/this-system-is-currently-not-set-up-to-build-kernel-modules-when-trying-to-ins) and [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-broken-packages-on-linux/) to try to solve it but didn't make any difference.

I'm running out of ideas. Anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks for the help!

I find it quite disappointing that supposedly stable versions of Ubuntu and VirtualBox don't work out of the box with clear installation instructions

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox uses a "kernel module" to do its thing.

Just as the text says above, you haven't got the tools to create that module.
SO: Your Virtualbox installation is not complete...

`$ sudo apt install build-essential` # will install `gcc` and `make`

On my 20.04 Ubuntu I have
`ii  perl`
`ii  perl-base`
`ii  perl-modules-5.30`

... included in the output of:
`$ dpkg -l | grep -E "^ii +perl[- ]+"`
... which I believe to be the complete base of perl *(I may be wrong)*.
And those `ii`'s - tells they are actually installed and I suspect that is the case in your 22.04 too.
*( `ii` --check-->  `$ dpkg -l | grep -B 100 "+++-"`)*.

When you have done/verified the above; **reinstall virtualbox**.